# Prove $n>1$ is prime $\iff \alpha^{n-1} = 1 \ \forall \alpha \in \mathbb Z_n\setminus\{[0]\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Prove $n>1$ is prime $\iff \alpha^{n-1} = 1 \ \forall \alpha \in \mathbb Z_n\setminus \{[0]\}$.

I have proven $\Rightarrow$ which is an immediate consequence of Euler's theorem, however I cannot seem to find an answer for $\Leftarrow$.

I've tried considering the contrapositive, but without luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a^k \equiv 1 \bmod n$ then $(a,n)=1$ because $a^k=1+nq$.

If this is true for all $a$ that are not a multiple of $n$, then $n$ must be prime, because $(n,d)=d$ if $d$ divides $n$.

Comment: Could this also be proven in terms of the order of $\alpha$ ?

Comment: @user111854, if $\alpha$ is not coprime with $n$, then the multiplicative order of $\alpha$ is not defined (or is $\infty$).

Comment: You are right. So the point is that $\phi(n) = n-1$ by your argument ?

Comment: @user111854, I guess so.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ihf. I guess I can use the result even thus Euclid Algorithm is not yet introduced in the book. The identity $a^k - nq = 1$ should make it obvious that if $c \mid a, n$ then  $c \mid 1$ which implies $c = \pm 1$.

Comment: @user111854, I didn't use Euclid's Algorithm, just the definition of $\equiv\bmod n$. Your argument is ok.

Comment: Ohh you are right, sorry. Don't know where I got that idea from.